# Merging multiple data frames by pasting alternative rows

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, rbind, cbind

I have spatial weather data of UK in Ascii text format for 7 years (each file/dataframe have monthly data of one year - 12 columns and 52201 rows as each row represents one location).
I want to merge data frames with alternative rows - 1st row of data frame 1 then 1st row of data frame 2 till 1st row of data frame 7 then 2nd row of data frame 1 till 2nd row of data frame 7 and continue ....

```
  V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9   V10   V11   V12
-1199 -1199 -1199 -1199 -1199 -1199 -1199 -1199 -1199 -1199 -1199 -1199
-1299 -1299 -1299 -1299 -1299 -1299 -1299 -1299 -1299 -1299 -1299 -1299
-1399 -1399 -1399 -1399 -1399 -1399 -1399 -1399 -1399 -1399 -1399 -1399
-9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999
-9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999 -9999
```

**Here is my code:**

```
n1<-read.table("data/y1call.txt", sep="")
n2<-read.table("data/y2call.txt", sep="")
n3<-read.table("data/y3call.txt", sep="")
c<-rbind(n1,n2,n3)
merge(n1,n2,n3)
```

I have tried `merge`, `rbind`, `cbind` but all failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new column representing the `rownames` in each data frame, and sort on that variable after you `rbind`, i.e.

```
ddf_all <- do.call(rbind, lapply(list(df1, df2, df3), function(i)transform(i, new = rownames(i))))
ddf_all[order(ddf_all$new),]
```

which gives,

> ```
>    v1 v2 new
> 1   1  6   1
> 6  11 16   1
> 11 21 26   1
> 2   2  7   2
> 7  12 17   2
> 12 22 27   2
> 3   3  8   3
> 8  13 18   3
> 13 23 28   3
> 4   4  9   4
> 9  14 19   4
> 14 24 29   4
> 5   5 10   5
> 10 15 20   5
> 15 25 30   5
> ```

**DATA:**

```
df1 <- data.frame(v1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), V2 = c(6, 7, 8, 9, 10))
df2 <- data.frame(v1 = c(11, 12, 13, 14, 15), v2 = c(16, 17, 18, 19, 20))
df3 <- data.frame(v1 = c(21, 22, 23, 24, 25), v2 = c(26, 27, 28, 29, 30))
```

Comment: Dear Sotos,
Thanks for your input and its working well but it's still there is some unexpected change. As the row sequence/order should be 1,6,11 and then 2,7,12 and so on but here in my case it is 1,6,11 but no 2,7,12 and something different order. Do you know why this can happen or any other solution?

Comment: I wouldn't know until I see an example that fails. I don't see anything flawed in the workflow. Are the individual data frames ordered? Do you need to order them individually before throwing them into a list?

Comment: `n1<-read.table("data/y1call.txt", sep="")`

`n2<-read.table("data/y2call.txt", sep="")`

`n3<-read.table("data/y3call.txt", sep="")`

`ddf_all<-do.call(rbind,lapply(list(n1,n2,n3), function(i)transform(i,new=rownames(i))))`

`change<- ddf_all[order(ddf_all$new),]`

Comment: Well, that does not help me. I do not have the files `data/y1call.txt`, ... :)

Comment: Can I get your email to send files and the code? Thanks

Comment: Just add a sample dataset that gives you the error (Here is a [link on how to make a good example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269))

Comment: When I am using data frame having more than 10 rows then it makes different sequence of rows, rather than 1,1,1 then 2,2,2 it actually makes makes 1,1,1 then 10,10,10 then 11,11,11. If I use less than data frame having less than 10 rows then it makes same sequence as in your example.

**There is no error, just the output is different than what I want, unfortunately.**

Comment: Please check these screenshots:
Script: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOU8I.jpg)
Input file: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mSjD.jpg)
Output file: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysGEX.jpg)